How to use “la spremuta“?
Can the word la spremuta, meaning freshly squeezed juice, be used without specifying a fruit like la spremuta d‘arancia?
Or rather, if I order una spremuta in a café, is it always understood as freshly squeezed orange juice?

Spremuta is a generic term and as  treccani.it suggests, it refers to:

“Il liquido che si ottiene spremendo. In particolare, bibita costituita da succo di frutti freschi, spesso addolcita con zucchero e allungata con acqua naturale o minerale: una spremuta di limone, d’arancia, di uva.”
(The liquid obtained by squeezing. In particular, a drink made from fresh fruit juice, often sweetened with sugar and diluted with natural or mineral water: freshly squeezed lemon, orange or grape juice)

the orange squeeze is probably the more common and popular one. I suggest you make clear what sort of “spremuta” you want, just to avoid misunderstanding.
